# Pandas partial index match on dataframes

Tags: pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have two pandas dataframes

```
import pandas as pd

# Sample MultiIndex
data1 = {
    'value': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60],
    'level_3': ['alpha','beta','gamma','delta','kappa','omega'],
    'level_1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    }

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
df1.set_index(['level_1', 'level_2','level_3'], inplace = True)
print(df1)
```

> ```
>                           value
> level_1 level_2 level_3       
> 1       A       alpha       10
> 2       B       beta        20
> 3       C       gamma       30
> 4       D       delta       40
> 5       E       kappa       50
> 6       F       omega       60
> ```

The second dataframe is like this

```
data2 = {
    'value': [300, 200],
    'level_5': ['jersey','michigan'],
    'level_2': ['A', 'B'],
    'level_1': [1, 2]
}

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
df2.set_index(['level_1', 'level_2','level_5'], inplace = True)
print(df2)
```

> ```
>                       value
> level_1 level_2 level_5        
> 1       A       jersey      300
> 2       B       michigan    200
> ```

Now I get the indexes of df2 into a variable

```
idxs2 = df2.index
print(idxs2)
```

> ```
> MultiIndex([(1, 'A',   'jersey'),
>             (2, 'B', 'michigan')],
>            names=['level_1', 'level_2', 'level_5'])
> ```

I need to first, find the index names common to df1 and df2 (i.e 'level_1' and 'level_2') and then borrow the values from df2 to df1. I don't know beforehand, which index names are common. In this case df1 rows (1,"A") and (2,"B") should be set to 300 and 200.

Comment: Can you provide the exact expected output for the second part of the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### Common levels

To get the common names use a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set) intersection:

```
out = set(df1.index.names) & set(df2.index.names)
```

Output: `{'level_1', 'level_2'}`

Or to have them in order of `df1` a list comprehension:

```
out = [n for n in df1.index.names if n in set(df2.index.names)]
```

Output: `['level_1', 'level_2']`

---

##### Custom combination

Now if I understood correctly the expected logic, what you want to do is not straightforward and you need to manually align the DataFrames on their unique levels by removing the extra levels with [`droplevel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.droplevel.html) and using [`combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) to combine the DataFrames in the desired order. End with [`set_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_axis.html) to restore the original index:

```
S1 = set(df1.index.names)    # {'level_1', 'level_2', 'level_3'}
S2 = set(df2.index.names)    # {'level_1', 'level_2', 'level_5'}

out = (df2
    .droplevel(list(S2-S1))  # removing 'level_3'
    .combine_first(df1.droplevel(list(S1-S2))) # removing 'level_5'
    .set_axis(df1.index)     # restoring the original levels
)

print(out)
```

Output:

```
                         value
level_1 level_2 level_3       
1       A       alpha      300
2       B       beta       200
3       C       gamma       30
4       D       delta       40
5       E       kappa       50
6       F       omega       60
```

Intermediates:

```
# df1.droplevel(list(S1-S2))
                 value
level_1 level_2       
1       A           10
2       B           20
3       C           30
4       D           40
5       E           50
6       F           60

# df2.droplevel(list(S2-S1))
                 value
level_1 level_2       
1       A          300
2       B          200
```

Answer (score 0):

Get same levels names by [`set.intersetion`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.intersection) and remove these levels by [`set.difference`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.difference) from both Dataframes by [`DataFrame.droplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.droplevel.html), so possible use [`DataFrame.update`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html), last set original indices and dtypes by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and [`DataFrame.astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html):

```
lvl = set(df1.index.names).intersection(df2.index.names)
print (lvl)
{'level_2', 'level_1'}

df11 = df1.droplevel(df1.index.names.difference(lvl))
df22 = df2.droplevel(df2.index.names.difference(lvl))

df11.update(df22)
print (df11)
                 value
level_1 level_2       
1       A        300.0
2       B        200.0
3       C         30.0
4       D         40.0
5       E         50.0
6       F         60.0

df = df11.set_index(df1.index).astype(df1.dtypes)
print (df)
                         value
level_1 level_2 level_3       
1       A       alpha      300
2       B       beta       200
3       C       gamma       30
4       D       delta       40
5       E       kappa       50
6       F       omega       60
```